# How to / where to find info on JBoss client dependencies? Any documentation?

Tags: jar, jboss, dependencies, ejb-3.0

It may be pretty basic question. But no luck Googling.

I was going through [this](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/j2ee/ejb3fromswing.html) URL. Because I had an issue accessing EJBs deployed on JBoss. After following this, it worked. Mainly this line.

```
 jboss-ejb3-client.jar, jboss-aop-jdk50-client.jar, jboss-aspect-jdk50-client.jar and jbossall-client.jar - 
 all these .jar files are found in client folder of JBoss installation directory
```

But for a newbie of EJBs like me, this is following the steps without understanding the dependencies. So my question, can we find documentation like this somewhere? How do we know the jars we need to copy to client application classpath?

Comment: Updated again. Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jbossall-client.jar for JBoss 4.X is enough - it contains all needed libraries.

For JBoss 5.X the story is more difficult - you need to reference in your project only jbossall-client.jar, but inside this JAR there are no actual classes, only MANIFEST file, which lists needed dependencies.

So, on JBoss 5, you need to have jbossall-client.jar added to classpath of your client plus all listed JARs lying next to it. Crazy, isnt't it?

JBoss 7 has sane approach. There is bin\client\jboss-client.jar that contains all dependencies needed by clients.

Comment: So for all JBoss client dependencies, we just need jboss-client.jar?

Comment: Part of the question is, how do we know we need to copy jboss-client.jar to our lib? Where is it documented?

Comment: For JBoss 7: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI For previous versions I couldn't find it (there are tons of hints on stackoverflow/blogs/etc, so it is hard to find it in official documentation)

Comment: Thanks, Again. That helps. Yes, we can find it online by searching. But I imagine there should be official document that should outline this.